# City parking in Perth, Western Australia

Tags: driving, automobiles, perth

How is the parking situation in the CBD of Perth, Western Australia? May I know is it easy to find & what is the normal rate? It's because I am planning straight away to Penguin Island after exploring the city.

If not is there any better ways to travel there? I found public transport is feasible there but like I mention before I need to travel to Penguin Island later.

Comment: If you are travelling to Penguin Island I struggle to find why you would want to park in the Perth CBD. Parking on the South Perth foreshore and catching the ferry would be a much better (and cheaper) option. It would also allow you to get right on the Kwinana Freeway (Rockingham [Penguin island] is about 50kms away from the CBD after all). Another frowned upon yet possible option is to park in Kings Park and catch the 37 bus into the CBD (it is free until the FTZ ends). Cars parked in Kings Park usually have the caveat that someone remains in the park, however this is a (free) option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is plenty of information available online which should help you plan your visit to Perth. [The City of Perth governmental website](http://www.transport.wa.gov.au/projects/perth-parking.asp) explains how parking works. Since you are not a resident you will have to look for street or underground parking. Luckily for you there is [a dedicated website showing different parking spaces and availabilities](https://www.cityofperthparking.com.au/):

[image: Perth Parking]

If all else fails, [the Parkopedia page on Perth](http://www.parkopedia.com.au/parking/locations/perth_western_australia_australia_qd66hrx48q4/?arriving=201703091630&leaving=201703091830) should help you find the right spot.